# Using scala.Future with Java 8 lambdas

Tags: java, scala, lambda, functional-programming

The scala `Future` class has  several methods that are based on functional programming.  When called from Java, it looks like using lambdas from Java 8 would be a natural fit.

However, when I try to actually use that, I run into several problems.  The following code does not compile

```
someScalaFuture.map(val -> Math.sqrt(val)).
       map(val -> val + 3);
```

because map takes an `ExecutionContext` as an implicit argument.  In Scala, you can (usually) ignore that, but it needs to be passed in explicitly in Java.

```
someScalaFuture.map(val -> Math.sqrt(val),
                    ec).
       map(val -> val + 3,
           ec);
```

This fails with this error:

```
error: method map in interface Future<T> cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] val),ExecutionContextExecutor
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) S
    (argument mismatch; Function1 is not a functional interface
      multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface Function1)
  where S,T are type-variables:
    S extends Object declared in method <S>map(Function1<T,S>,ExecutionContext)
    T extends Object declared in interface Future
```

If I actually create an anonymous class extending Function1 and implement `apply` as such:

```
    someScalaFuture.map(new Function1<Double, Double>() {
            public double apply(double val) { return Math.sqrt(val); }
        },
        ec).
        map(val -> val + 3,
            ec);
```

I get an error that

```
error: <anonymous com.example.MyTestClass$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method apply$mcVJ$sp(long) in Function1
```

I have not tried implementing that method (and am not sure if you can even implement a method with dollar signs in the  middle of the name), but this looks like I am starting to wonder into the details of Scala implementations.

Am I going down a feasible path?  Is there a reasonable way to use lambdas in this way?  If there is a library that makes this work, that is an acceptable solution.  Ideally, something like

```
import static org.thirdparty.MakeLambdasWork.wrap;
...
   wrap(someScalaFuture).map(val -> Math.sqrt(val)).
         map(val -> val + 3);
```

Comment: What version of Scala are you trying to do this with?

Comment: I am using Scala 2.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) library provides interoperability between Scala 2.11 and Java 8 lambdas.

Answer (score 4):

As @Seth mentioned you can use [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat)

```
import scala.concurrent.Future;
import static scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters.globalExecutionContext;
import static scala.compat.java8.JFunction.func;
...

Future<Object> future = ...;

future.onComplete(
    func(x -> ...), /// wraps Java lambda into a Scala Function
    globalExecutionContext());// Gets the global execution context.
```

However, [Scala 2.12 introduced features to make it more compatible with Java](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0), now you can use lambdas directly

```
Future<Object> future = ...;

future.onComplete(
    x -> ..., // Uses Java lambda directly
    globalExecutionContext()); // Gets the global execution context.
```

`ExecutionContext.global` basically is an execution context backed by a `ForkJoinPool` that manages a limited amount of threads.

If you need to get more information about it I recommend these two links

[Execution Context in Futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#execution-context)

[When in doubt, stick with scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global](http://blog.jessitron.com/2014/02/scala-global-executioncontext-makes.html)